# Jquery ajax data convert to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my jquery ajax. I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
    success: function(data){
        status = data;
    },
    async: false
});

if(status == "Password correct")
{
    //do something
}
```

Basically, I want to capture the "data" that was returned on "success". But I cannot make a way for the if statement to work. I am think the "data" was not a string so I cannot make a comparison.

Comment: have you checked the data returning, try alert(data); first

Comment: @nbrooks He has `async: false`. But comebal - you probably shouldn't code that way.

Comment: @Ariel Wow, completely missed that lol

Comment: @comebal can you show the value for data...I think data is in some other format like JSON or something else

Comment: @Ariel so should I take it away? I'm just a beginner so I don't really get things yet.

Comment: @AntGuider I can alert the data, its showing "Password correct" but I don't know why its not working when I try to do an IF statement

Comment: @comebal: Try and read more about ajax - go for [wschools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_examples.asp) & [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) There are examples will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define **status** outside ajax call. then access that everywhere.

```
var status = '';
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        status = data;
    },

});

if(status == "Password correct")
{
    //do something
}
```

At **users/validatepassword** use **json_encode()**

```
echo json_encode("Password correct");
```

Comment: Thank you. You actually solved my problem. I did some little modifications and it worked. >:D<

Comment: @comebal: I'm glad that I was able to help.

Comment: Tip: use `dataType: "text"` or `dataType: "xml"` for TXT or for XML.

Answer (score 4):

Try status checking condition inside the ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
    success: function(data){
        status = data;
        if(status == "Password correct")
        {
         //do something
        }
    },
    async: false
});
```

if the condition is outside ajax, It will execute before the ajax return.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
 var response = $.ajax({
            url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        if(response == "Password correct")
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You see you should process the message within the success function not from outside.

```
var status = '';
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        status = data;
        if(status == "Password correct")
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Comebal: Buddy this is what u need to do:

Firstly remove the async:false

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/validatepassword/'+current,
    success: function(data){
       //alert(data); 
       if(data == "Password correct")
        {
                  //do something
        }
    }
});
```

Then, the major part is make sure data from ajax page is "Password correct" or else u can't "do something"... :)